# Is it possible to walk faster?

Tags: cyber-knights

Is there any way for me to increase my walking speed since it takes forever to cover a large zone.  Is there an augmentation or some drugs for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are also multiple types of alternate transport around the city.  For example, Ricco's Board SERV in Dorchester will take you quickly around the eastern coast of the harbor.  The Canal Taxi-SERV in Charles Canal will take you down the canal deep into Los V territory.  The Knight Horizon run Thopter services that will hop you across town in a blink of an eye if you know the right people, and if you climb the right ladder, BraveStar will give you access to their secure transportation line as well.

Also, to walk really fast just turn of the "Animated Walk Option" in the options menu.  Then you will zoom around!

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't found anything that helps me walk faster.  What has helped is obtaining multiple v-chips from taxi drivers (intervene when you see citizens being harassed by enforcers).  This lets me take multiple taxis at a time while waiting for the other ones to cool down.

Of course, you can't do this while your heat is too high or if you are on an escort mission, but otherwise this is the best way to travel around the NBZ.